# sender address must contain a domain in While Sent NewsLetter magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, newsletter, domain

I am working with Newsletter in **Magento 2**.

I have follow this link http://blog.belvg.com/newsletters-in-magento-2-0.html to Configure NewsLetter in Magento 2.

After Queueing Newsletter, admin side changes status "Not Sent" to **Sent**.

But, throws an error in **CustomerSupport: sender address must contain a domain**

In `newsletter_problem` table and **Report-> NewsLetter Problem** in admin side.

But, All the Mail function working fine like subscription mail, new account mail.

Suggest me why this problem occur and how to solve this.

Comment: The error message: `sender address must contain a domain`?

Comment: yes, @KhoaTruongDinh  I update answer check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using magento 2.0.8. I have checked  newsletter module

> module-newsletter/Model/Queue.php

Core Code: line no:239

> ->setFrom( ['name' => $this->getNewsletterSenderEmail(), 'email' => $this->getNewsletterSenderName()])

change like this:

> ->setFrom( ['name' => $this->getNewsletterSenderName(), 'email' => $this->getNewsletterSenderEmail()])

Now, Newsletter Sent Successfully. i don't know its bug in magento 2.0.8.